# Rails model associates another model more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I got a model called Pages that looks like this:

```
title
description
image_id
background_image
logo
```

I also got a model calles Images that looks like this:

```
id
title
```

What I would like to be able to is to associate these three fields with the image model.

```
image_id
background_image
logo
```

image_id works perfectly because of the Page model association:

```
has_many :images
```

How do I make it work with background_image and logo?
 Hope my question makes any sense. Thanks

**UPDATE**
[image]

Comment: You mean you want to access an image's page attributes through an image instance? Do you have a `belongs_to: page` association in your Image model? That and `delegate :background_image, :to => :page` should do the trick. Also, not sure why you'd want to access image_id when it's the same value as image.id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Page` model, you'll want to use `belongs_to` to specify that it contains a pointer to an `Image`.  For the first one, that'll just be `belongs_to :image`.

But you want to have three pointers. You can do that; for each of the other fields, you'll add an option to `belongs_to` to specify that it's pointing to an `Image`.  You do that using the `:class_name` option, like this;

```
belongs_to :logo, :class_name => 'Image'
```

You'll also probably want to name your columns with `_id` at the end, so `background_image_id` and `logo_id` - it's more Railsy that way.

All of this is documented in the Rails Guides; the `:class_name` option is specifically [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-class_name).